# Appending the query params the right way when using proxy_pass with nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, querystring

I have my nginx proxy pass config setup as follows:

```
location /try-me {
   proxy_pass https://some-domain.com?id=true&zone=false
}
```

This works fine. But the problem is when someone from the browser tries

```
https://mywebsite.com/try-me?ping=true&foo=bar
```

The final URL that gets created after the proxy_pass is:

```
https://some-domain.com?id=true&zone=false?ping=true&foo=bar
```

The query parameter formation is completely incorrect. How can I make sure that Nginx **appends** any query parameters forwarded in the following manner:

```
id=true&zone=false&ping=true&foo=bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to use `rewrite...break` rather than trying to get `proxy_pass` to do it properly.

For example:

```
location /try-me {
    rewrite ^ /?id=true&zone=false break;
    proxy_pass https://some-domain.com;
}
```

The `rewrite` directive will append the original parameters correctly. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

In the above example, any URI that begins with `/try-me` will be rewritten to `/` with the adjusted query string.